# Execute a Maven plugin with --enable-preview in POM

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have a custom Maven plugin which makes use of JDK 12 preview features. I compile the plugin setting `--enable-preview` as compiler arg, i.e.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <compilerArgs>
            <compilerArg>--enable-preview</compilerArg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I want to execute the plugin, I add the plugin like this in the POM:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>my.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>my-goal</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But this fails with:

```
Preview features are not enabled for MyPluginMojo. Try running with '--enable-preview'
```

How can I enable preview features in a plugin execution?

Comment: Simple answer you can not...cause a plugin is executed within the context of a given build which uses a given JDK ...I don't know why you are using preview features of a JDK within a plugin ? Does not make sense from my point of view...Apart from that this means you can not run your build with earlier JDK version by using the implemented plugin ...?

Comment: Just wanted to start using the new switch statement; if it's not possible to enable preview features on a plugin execution, I'll just don't use them! Thanks!

Comment: See also [Compile a JDK12 preview feature with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52232681/1744774).

Answer (score 5):

For me, I had to add a config file to my build directory at:

```
.mvn/jvm.config
```

containing:

```
--enable-preview
```

This will make sure that Maven passes the correct parameters to JVM

Comment: I've added this file but still getting errors. Any help? "error: records are a preview feature and are disabled by default."

Answer (score 3):

You made a mistake in your pom. `<compilerArgs>` takes nested `<arg>`, like so:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>17</source>
                <target>17</target>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>--enable-preview</arg>
                 </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

For JDK 17, this works for me:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <source>17</source>
    <target>17</target>
    <compilerArgs>--enable-preview</compilerArgs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```