# Maven Exec Plugin with Preview Features

Tags: java, maven, maven-exec-plugin, java-14, preview-feature

It's easy to compile your Java sources with `--enable-preview`:

```
<!-- Enable preview features -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <release>15</release>
        <compilerArgs>--enable-preview</compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But how can you then run `exec:java`? Using

```
<!-- Exec plugin.. run with `mvn exec:java` -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
        <commandlineArgs>--enable-preview</commandlineArgs>
        <arguments>
            <argument>--enable-preview</argument>
        </arguments>
        </systemProperties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Still results in the following error:

```
An exception occured while executing the Java class. 
Preview features are not enabled for Main (class file version 59.65535). 
Try running with '--enable-preview'
```

Comment: During the time when Java-12 was in development, I remember trying this out with the shade plugin creating a jar and executing using the java command line, the steps for that are listed [under this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52232681/compile-and-execute-a-jdk-preview-feature-with-maven).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that exec:java runs in the same maven  java process, which by default isn't started with `--enable-preview`.

You could instead switch to `exec:exec`, but one way to still use exec:java is to create a `.mvn/jvm.config` file containing `--enable-preview`. You can put this in your project's root directory and check into git. Or create a MAVEN_OPTS environment variable.

Reference: https://maven.apache.org/configure.html

Comment: I have tried this approach with toolchain, it did not work, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73830548/exec-java-goal-with-toolchain-can-not-enable-preview-features