# Maven exec plugin with toolchain can not enable preview features

Tags: maven, exec-maven-plugin, maven-toolchains-plugin

I want to taste the newest Java 19 feature, also do not change the default Java Home( Java 17).

So I create a *toolchains.xml* in the *~/.m2*, and define a `jdk` type toolchain like this.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<toolchains>
  <!-- JDK toolchains -->
  <toolchain>
    <type>jdk</type>
    <provides>
      <version>1.8</version>
      <vendor>oracle</vendor>
    </provides>
    <configuration>
      <jdkHome>D:/jdks/jdk8</jdkHome>
    </configuration>
  </toolchain>
  <toolchain>
    <type>jdk</type>
    <provides>
      <version>11</version>
      <vendor>oracle</vendor>
    </provides>
    <configuration>
      <jdkHome>D:/jdks/jdk11</jdkHome>
    </configuration>
  </toolchain>
   <toolchain>
    <type>jdk</type>
    <provides>
      <version>17</version>
      <vendor>oracle</vendor>
    </provides>
    <configuration>
      <jdkHome>D:/jdks/jdk17</jdkHome>
    </configuration>
  </toolchain>
    <toolchain>
    <type>jdk</type>
    <provides>
      <version>19</version>
      <vendor>oracle</vendor>
    </provides>
    <configuration>
      <jdkHome>D:/jdks/jdk-19</jdkHome>
    </configuration>
  </toolchain>
  <!-- other toolchains -->
  <toolchain>
    <type>netbeans</type>
    <provides>
      <version>15</version>
    </provides>
    <configuration>
      <installDir>D:/devtools/netbeans</installDir>
    </configuration>
  </toolchain>
</toolchains>
```

Then I added the following plugins in my project POM.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>--enable-preview</arg>             
        </compilerArgs>
        <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>toolchain</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <toolchains>
            <jdk>
                <version>19</version>
                <vendor>oracle</vendor>
            </jdk>
        </toolchains>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.example.demo.RecordPatternExample</mainClass>
        <commandlineArgs>--enable-preview</commandlineArgs>
        <arguments>
            <argument>--enable-preview</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

As suggested [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60922845/maven-exec-plugin-with-preview-features), I also added `--enable-preview` to the *.mvn/jvm.config*.

But when running the project in command line.

```bash
mvn clean package exec:java
```

I still got the exception like this.

```bash
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ record-pattern ---
[INFO] Toolchain in maven-compiler-plugin: JDK[D:/jdks/jdk-19]
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to D:\hantsylabs\java-sandbox\record-pattern\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ record-pattern ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\hantsylabs\java-sandbox\record-pattern\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ record-pattern ---
[INFO] Toolchain in maven-compiler-plugin: JDK[D:/jdks/jdk-19]
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ record-pattern ---
[INFO] Toolchain in surefire-plugin: JDK[D:/jdks/jdk-19]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ record-pattern ---
[INFO] Building jar: D:\hantsylabs\java-sandbox\record-pattern\target\record-pattern-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:java (default-cli) @ record-pattern ---
[WARNING]
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/example/demo/RecordPatternExample has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 63.65535), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 61.0
```

Obviously the `--enable-preview` option was not applied with `exec:java` and toolchain configured JDK, but it worked well with maven-compiler-plugin.

The [sample project](https://github.com/hantsy/java-sandbox/tree/master/record-pattern) is shared on my Github.

Comment: `toolchain.xml` or `toolchains.xml`? should be the latter, but you wrote the former. did the compiler plugin pick up your toolchain configuration?

Comment: Yes, it is `toolchains.xml`. The compiler plugin is working well and picked up the `--enable-preview` arguments. But there is no way to make exec  plugin working as expected.

Comment: the error message does not seem to be about not having `--enable-preview`, but not using toolchain configuration altogether. However, if compiler plugin picked up the new toolchain, so should exec:java.

Comment: is your toolchains.xml somewhere in its entirety? don't see it in the github repo

Comment: can you also please try running `mvn toolchains:toolchain exec:java` and see if that works

Comment: Did not work.

I have run the `mvn clean package exec:java` again, and  updated the whole log of `compile`, `testCompile` and `test`, and `exec:java`, it seems `exec` does not run against the toolchain configured JDK.

Comment: From the [exec plugin doc](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-using-toolchains.html), jdk type toolchain should be enabled by default.

Comment: did you add your full toolchains.xml somewhere so we can see it?

Comment: @eis Updated and pasted my complete toolchains.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investigated this, and to me it seems this cannot be done: `exec:java` doesn't seem to have toolchains support. If you look at [ExecJavaMojo source code](https://github.com/mojohaus/exec-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/exec/ExecJavaMojo.java) which is used for `exec:java`, you see it has no references to toolchain, so it can't work. Compare that with [ExecMojo source code](https://github.com/mojohaus/exec-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/exec/ExecMojo.java#L867-L921) that has them.

If you change your configuration to use `exec:exec` instead, setup should work:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <executable>java</executable>
        <arguments>
            <argument>--enable-preview</argument>
            <argument>-classpath</argument>
            <classpath/>
            <argument>com.example.demo.RecordPatternExample</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Test run using `mvn exec:exec` with toolchains configured:

```
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:exec (default-cli) @ record-pattern ---
[INFO] Toolchain in exec-maven-plugin: JDK[C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-19+36]
Hantsy Bai
Circle with r:1.2, area:4.5216
Square with x:1.2, area:1.44
Rectangle with x: 1.0 and y:2.0, area:2.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.350 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-10-12T13:25:56+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/25M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: It seems like a bug.

Comment: @Hantsy toolchain support might not be possible to implement with exec:java. The point of that goal is to execute in the same VM as maven run, and it might not be possible to use some other toolchain within the same VM.

Comment: As the documentation doesn't claim exec:java supports toolchains, I'm thinking rather a missing feature than a bug.

Comment: I hope it is enabled by default when running application(align with compiler and surefire plugins), and  use a configuration option to select use toolchain or not.  Like we use NetBeans IDE(eg.  use Java 19 to start) to build a Java 11 project(select a different JDK for project), when build and run the project in IDE, we never use the IDE scoped Java 19.