# "Records" preview feature in IntelliJ 2020.1 with Java 14 fails with compiler error during Maven `install`, but runs otherwise

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, java-record

I am trying to use the [JEP 359: Records (Preview)](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/359) feature in Java with [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) 2020.1.1 RC.

I defined a class like this:

```
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.LocalTime;

public record LocalTimeRange(LocalTime start , LocalTime stop)
{
}
```

When I run a main method in another class using this `LocalTimeRange` class, no problem.

When I do a Maven `install` I get this error:

> Error:(6,8) java: records are a preview feature and are disabled by default.

➥ How can I help Maven complete its `install` operation?

I used the [*Maven Quickstart Archetype*](https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/), version 1.4. I then edited the POM to use all the latest versions of its various dependencies.

---

I have "Project Structure" settings:

> Project Settings > Project > Project SDK > 14
>
> Project Settings > Project > Project language level > 14 (Preview) - Records, patterns, text blocks
>
> Project Settings > Modules > Project language level > 14 (Preview) - Records, patterns, text blocks

I have "Preferences" settings:

> Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler > Per-module bytecode version > Target bytecode version > 14

Running this Java:
openjdk 14.0.1 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 14.0.1+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing)

Using:

IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.1 (Ultimate Edition)

Build #IU-201.7223.58, built on April 26, 2020

Subscription is active until August 28, 2020

Runtime version: 11.0.6+8-b765.40 x86_64

VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14.6

GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep

Memory: 2200M

Cores: 6

Non-Bundled Plugins: com.github.leomillon.uuidgenerator

Comment: By any chance is there a way for you to ["(use --enable-preview to enable records)"](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-237538)?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The bug in that ticket [*IDEA-237538*](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-237538) does seem to be my problem. I added a comment on that page documenting my particulars. Thank you for providing that link.

Comment: I'm not planning to upgrade for a little bit yet. Hope they work the kinks out.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Oddly, my code runs. I can instantiate my `record` class, and call its methods. Only the Maven `install` throws this error. So for a simple little app just to play with `record`, the bug does not bite. Only for a complex app that requires a Maven `install` is a problem.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch If you make an Answer of your comment, I will accept it.

Comment: That's okay. I literally just got lucky on my search query. Feel free and self answer if you think it's worthwhile. I'm not using Java 14 yet (as I mentioned).

Comment: Glad that I wasn't tempted by the balloon pop-up for the update. :) But did you not perform `mvn verify` from the terminal, just to compare the IDE to the command line?

Comment: @Naman No I did not. I do not know about Maven `verify`.

Comment: Related: [*IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.1 (Ultimate Edition) can't detect JDK 14 record as reserved keyword*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61925053/642706)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a fresh issue or bug that arrived around IntelliJ 2020.1.1 RC build # 201. Same behavior in final release of 2020.1.1.

See ticket # IDEA-237538, [*IntelliJ Build #IU-201.6668.121 no longer recognizes Java 14 records*](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-237538)

## Workaround: Add `<configuration>` elements

To make your Maven `clean` & `install` complete successfully, add `<configuration>` elements to two of your POM elements, to flag `--enable-preview`.

Change this:

```
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
            </plugin>
```

…to this:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>14</release>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>--enable-preview</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>--enable-preview</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Based on the edit, related to [Compile and execute a JDK preview feature with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52232681/compile-and-execute-a-jdk-preview-feature-with-maven)