# How to run a single Java file with preview features enabled in Netbeans 12?

Tags: java, netbeans, preview-feature, netbeans-12

I have created a Java Maven project with Java version 14 in Netbeans. I have [already instructed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52232682/507738) the compiler to enable preview features, and that works.

Now I have a bunch of classes containing main methods, and I want to execute one of them using `right-click on file » Run File`. But I get a `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError` saying that "Preview features are not enabled". How can I execute the **Run File** action with preview features enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be configured within the project properties.

1. Right-click on the project and select **Properties**.
2. Select **Actions** in the left menu.
3. A list of actions is presented. Select **Run file via main()**.
4. Edit the `exec.args` property by adding `--enable-preview` immediately behind the equals sign.